# Conversion from string "0.##" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am doing a simple conversion from decimal to string and stripping trailing zeros like so:

argCat.ToString("0.##")

however, i keep getting the following error:

Conversion from string "0.##" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would happen if `argCat` is of a type that does not have a `ToString()` overload that accepts a parameter.

In such a case, your code is parsed as `ToString()("0.##")`; the `"0.##"` becomes an argument to the indexer in the `String` returned by `ToString()`.
You then get this misleading error because that indexer takes an int, not a string.

Comment: @TanyaXrum: It depends.  What type is `argCat`?

Comment: that was it. i chagned it to: CType(argCat, String)

Comment: Use `string.Format(...)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

string str =  String.Format("{0:C}", argCat);